# auto py to exe the exe that is created just closes

Tags: python, exe

```
import bezier
import numpy as np
nodes1 = np.asfortranarray([
    [0.0, 0.5, 1.0],
    [0.0, 1.0, 0.0],
])
curve1 = bezier.Curve(nodes1, degree=2)
print(curve1)
input("test")
```

closes right after it opens the cmd and prints nothing.
what should i do i have tried adding bezier and numpy as hidden imports still same issue.
using windows virtual machine when complied on mac has no issue

Thanks so much for the help in advance!

I also have a much larger script but this is the demo script where the same issue apply's to both but this is simpler because its smaller.

Comment: I just want to be sure: Do you want the windows to close after you run the program or do you want it to stay open? Do you want it as py file or exe file? Your question isn't clear

Comment: no i dont want it too

Answer (score 1):

You can try to freeze the screen at the end of the program like this:

```
while True:
    pass
```

or using `sleep()` method.

If you do that, the program won't do anything when it reaches these lines. The program will freeze and look like it stops working, but it won't close also (to close the program you will need to use `ctrl+c` on the keyboard).

Comment: And it didn't work? try to use `loop` instead or `sleep()` method